# 3D Transformation in Java

Tags: java, 3d, 2d, transform

I have to write a program which draws lots of triangles. I have got 3D-coordinates but I want to draw them in 2D. My problem is that I am not understanding how I can transform the coordinates and the websites I found never had got an example, so e. g. I got A(3|1.5|-0.5), B(4|2.5|-1) & C(5|1|-1.5) and I am standing ad ViewingPoint(4|2|10). What are the new coordinates and how I get them?

Comment: Don't forget to tell us if your question has been correctly answered by accepting it! Otherwise, clarify your issue with comments and if necessary edits to your question (like code).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you would do this like that :

```
u = x/z; //u is your x in 2D
v = y/z; //v is your y in 2D
```

- u and v are your new coordinates in 2D for a specific point
- and x, y and z are your old 3D coordinates for that point

I am adding this link to my answer as this is the math behind my answer :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection?oldformat=true

Comment: why all the downvotes, I'll sure improve a lot from downvoting for no obvious reason